# How pull wordpress blog data using Blogger API using python

Tags: xml-rpc, plugin-json-api, blogger

Wordpress mentioned that it supports Blogger API ([link)](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Blogger_API). So, can anyone tell me how to use Blogger API (using python) v3 to pull wordpress public blogs data.

Or, is there any wordpress API to pull public data from its blogs? (Lang: Python).

Any useful documentation that clearly explains the procedure would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try [python-wordpress-xmlrpc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/2.0). See [documentation](http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and [GitHub repository](https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/).

I haven’t tested it for myself, but it looks promising.

Comment: Okay. but I looked over the documentation and found that it doesn't have any OAuth mechanism or any connection with Google API. The lib directly take `username` and `password` as arguments. Is it safe to deploy such details directly on cloud?

Comment: I would not send the log-in details over an unencrypted network. But there are plugins like [One-Time Password](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-time-password/) – this should help.

Comment: actually I will be using this in a facebook web application (Django).. So, I am quite looking for a more secured environment like OAuth. Anyway, the wp docs mentioned that they support Blogger API.. how to use it for WP??

Comment: That’s a separate question (and maybe already answered here somewhere).